# Occasionally getting connection reset by peer when uploading_from_string to google cloud storage python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

Roughly 1 in 10 times an image is uploaded to google cloud storage, I get this error back. This code has been running for months, and after checking the logs I can see this error has persisted for a few weeks. Most images are getting uploaded which is why it's taken so long to identify. The exact error I see in the logs is: **HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with URL: *my_url*?uploadType=multipart (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))** Does anyone know what could cause this?

My code is very basic:

```
from google.cloud import storage

image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
jsonCreds  = f"{Home}/Config/gcp_secret.json"
bucketName = os.environ.get('GCP_BUCKET')
storageClient = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(jsonCreds)
retval, gcpImageBuffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
gcpByteArray = gcpImageBuffer.tobytes()

bucket = storageClient.bucket(bucketName)
Create the full file path to save the image in the format YYYY/MM/DD/<AssetID>.jpg
assetID = IPAddress         
imageFileName = imagePath.split('/')[-1]
components = imageFileName.split('_')
year  = components[0]
month = components[1]
day   = components[2]
hour  = components[3]
minute= components[4]
second= components[5]

#change filename to assetid_timestamp

# uuidName=str( uuid.uuid4() )
gcpFilePath = "{}/{}/{}/{}_{}_{}_{}".format(year,month,day,assetID,hour,minute,second)

blob = bucket.blob(gcpFilePath)
blob.upload_from_string(gcpByteArray)
```